# Magic Mouse 2 lagging

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have a Magic Mouse 2 which is approx 1 year old. Recently it has started lagging on my 2018 Macbook Pro 15 inch.

I can not see anything that is taking a lot of resources and I don't have external Bluetooth devices except my Apple Keyboard (Same age).

This has started in the last two weeks[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse? Ideally a wired USB mouse. That will tell you if it's the mouse or the system having a problem?

Comment: @Nic I bought a Magic Track Pad and I run them side-by-side. It's the magic mouse.

Comment: As a followup, I did remove all my Bluetooth devices and re-installed the keyboard, mouse and a new magic trackpad

Trackpad and keyboard work fine. Mouse is terrible.